# How do I resample and interpolate timeseries data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I have measurements that have been recorded approximately every 5 minutes:

```
2012-07-09T05:30:01+02:00   1906.1  1069.2  1093.2  3   1071.0  1905.7  
2012-07-09T05:35:02+02:00   1905.7  1069.2  1093.0  0   1071.5  1905.7  
2012-07-09T05:40:02+02:00   1906.1  1068.7  1093.2  0   1069.4  1905.7  
2012-07-09T05:45:02+02:00   1905.7  1068.4  1093.0  1   1069.6  1905.7  
2012-07-09T05:50:02+02:00   1905.7  1068.2  1093.0  4   1073.3  1905.7
```

The first column is the data's timestamp. The remaining columns are the recorded data.

I need to resample my data so that I have one row every 15 minutes, e.g. something like:

```
2012-07-09T05:15:00 XX XX XX XX XX XX
2012-07-09T05:30:00 XX XX XX XX XX XX
....
```

(In addition, there may be gaps in the recorded data and I would like gaps of more than, say, one hour to be replaced with a row of `NA` values.)

I can think of several ways to program this by hand, but is there built-in support for doing that kind of stuff in R? I've looked at the different libraries for dealing with timeseries data (`zoo`, `chron` etc) but couldn't find anything satisfactory.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Have you managed to find a package / solution for this?

Comment: @Rhubarb Did you have a look at `xts`? The package allows at least for downsampling. `to.period`, etc. (added the answer as well)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `approx` or the related `approxfun`. If `t` is the vector consisting of the timepoints where your data was sampled and if `y` is the vector with the data then `f <- approxfun(t,y)` creates a function `f` that linearly interpolates the data points in between the time points.

Example:

```
# irregular time points at which data was sampled
t <- c(5,10,15,25,30,40,50)
# measurements 
y <- c(4.3,1.2,5.4,7.6,3.2,1.2,3.7)

f <- approxfun(t,y)

# get interpolated values for time points 5, 20, 35, 50
f(seq(from=5,to=50,by=15))
[1] 4.3 6.5 2.2 3.7
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for built-in downsampling (upsampling is not supported), you can also use the `xts` package.

```
data(sample_matrix)
samplexts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
to.monthly(samplexts)
to.yearly(samplexts)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a good discussion of this on CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31666/how-can-i-align-synchronize-two-signals .  The author of that answer "rolled his own" interpolate-and-resample code.

Answer (score -5):

you should have a look in the openair package which has plenty of 'tools' for playing with time series data.

Comment: This isn't worth an answer on it's own as it is hardly helping. Any reader of this answer is still left on its own figuring out if the 'tools' include support for gap handling and resampling.